# Why does combining two shifts of a uint8_t produce a different result?

Tags: c, bit-shift, integer-promotion

Could someone explain me why:

```
x = x << 1;
x = x >> 1;
```

and:

```
x = (x << 1) >> 1;
```

produce different answers in C? `x` is a *uint8_t* type (unsigned 1-byte long integer). For example when I pass it `128 (10000000)` in the first case it returns `0` (as expected most significant bit falls out) but in the second case it returns the original `128`. Why is that? I'd expect these expressions to be equivalent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is due to integer promotions, both operands of the bit-wise shifts will be promoted to *int* in both cases. In the second case:

```
x = (x << 1) >> 1;
```

the result of `x << 1` will be an *int* and therefore the shifted bit will be preserved and available to the next step as an *int* which will shift it back again. In the first case:

```
x = x << 1;
x = x >> 1;
```

when you assign back to `x` you will lose the extra bits. From the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.7 Bit-wise shift operators` it says:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.

The integer promotions are covered in section `6.3.1.1` *Boolean, characters, and integers* paragraph *2* which says:

> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer
>   promotions.<sup>48)</sup>

The last piece of this why does the conversion from the *int* value `256` to *uint8_t* give us `0`? The conversion is covered in section `6.3.1.3` *Signed and unsigned integers* which is under the *Conversions* section and says:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>49)</sup>

So we have `256 - (255+1)` which is `0`.

Answer (score 7):

When you bitshift the result is promoted to `int`. In the first example you convert int back to uint8_t everytime, and lose the intermediate data. But in the second example you keep the int result when you shift back.