# Bitshifting in C++ producing the wrong answer

Tags: c++, shift

I tried running the following code code:

```
char c = (2 << 7) >> 7
```

which should return 0 because 2 has this binary representation as a `char`:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

After 7 shifts left, we get

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then, after seven shifts right, we get

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

However, I'm getting the result as 2, not 0.

The compiler says that `2 << 7` is 256, but it's a `char` and so it shouldn't be 256.

I understand that the `2 << 7` will be calculated as `int`s and the answer will be put into `c` so `256 >> 7` is 2.

I tried to cast 2 to char (ex: `(char)2>>7`) but it doesn't work either.

I'm trying to extract each bit from the `char`, so I wrote this code:

```
char c = 0x02;
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    char current = (c<<i)>>7;
}
```

How can I get each bit? What's wrong with my way?

Comment: `2<<7` is *not* a `char`.

Comment: Please don't replace your question text with "fixed it thanks" if you figure out what's wrong. Instead, add an answer explaining what was wrong.

Comment: I forget but this is a dupe for sure.

Comment: @haccks well [this is similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702091/why-does-combing-two-shifts-of-a-uint8-t-produce-a-different-result/22702107#22702107) but not exactly a dup. I am sure you will find a bunch of similar ones. I suppose it depends on how strict you are with the term dup.

Comment: Even if you cast the first operand like `(char)2>>7`, it won't work because of default promotion rule. All types narrower than int will be automatically promoted to int and there's no way to do maths on char or short, etc, except on a non standard compiler

Answer (score 7):

The result of an arithmetic shift operation with one operand being an `int` in C++ is always an `int`. Therefore, when you write

```
current = (c << i) >> 7;
```

C++ will interpret `(c << i)` and `(c << i) >> 7` as `int`s, casting back to a `char` only when the assignment is done. Since the temporary values are `int`s, no overflow occurs and the result should come out to the integer result casted to a `char`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How come int to char conversion (demotion) is not warned in c++? Why doesnt it require explicit casting? C++ is type strict right?

Comment: @texasbruce C++ permits implicit conversions between its primitive integer types without explicit casts. If you crank up the warning settings on your compiler, you might get a warning about it, though it's not required. While C++ does have static typing, since it explicitly allows these conversions, there's no type error.

Comment: "one operand" --> "the left operand".  The type of the right operand doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 4):

To get each bit, you could write:

```
(c >> i) & 0x01
```

Advantage: It works for any integer type.

Comment: Yes this is the way to do. On some platforms this is just a single bit test instruction. Shifting over the type's max may invoke undefined behavior

Answer (score 4):

According to 5.8 [expr.shift] paragraph 1:

> ... The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. ...

This for a left argument of type `char` together with the rules on integer promotion (4.5 [conv.prom]) says that the result is `int`. Of course, an `int` can hold the result of `2 << 7`. You can easily verify this behavior, too:

```
#include <iostream>

void print(char c) { std::cout << "char=" << int(c) << "\n"; }
void print(int i) { std::cout << "int=" << i << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    print(2 << 7);
}
```

The most simple approach to get the bits of a value is to use a `std::bitset<N>` with `N` being the digits of the corresponding unsigned type, e.g.:

```
char c('a');
std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits> bits(c);
```

If you want to get bits yourself you'd mask the bits using its `unsigned` counterpart of the integer type, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
void get_bits(T val)
{
    typedef typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type U;
    U value(val);
    for (std::size_t s(std::numeric_limits<U>::digits); s-- != 0; ) {
        std::cout << bool(value & (1u << s));
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```