# Why does compound bit shifting not set leading nibble to 0?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am trying to clear the first nibble in a 16-bit unsigned integer (set it to 0).

One of the approaches I attempted was to use left bit shifting and then right bit shifting to clear the first four bits.

Here is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint16_t x = 0xabcd; // I want to print out "bcd"
    uint16_t a = (x << 4) >> 4;

    printf("After clearing first four bits: %x\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting the first bit shift `(x << 4)` to evaluate to `0xbcd0` and then the right bit shift to push a leading `0` in front - `0x0bcd`. However, the actual output is `0xabcd`.

What confuses me more is if I try to use the same approach to clear the last four bits,

```
uint16_t a = (x >> 4) << 4;
```

it works fine and I get expected output: `abc0`.

Why, in the program above, does the right bit shifting not push a leading 0?

Comment: Think of `(x << 4) >> 4` as an expression. Only limited by the architecture's (native) word size. [what ever that is] see: integer promotion rules.

Comment: Note: You  are trying to clear the first nibble (or half-byte), not the first byte.

Comment: On a 16-bit `int/unsigned` system, the result would be `0bcd` as expected.

Comment: there are a lot more duplicates although it's a bit hard to search [Bitshifting in C++ producing the wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24100576/995714), [Why does combining two shifts of a uint8_t produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22702091/995714), [Unexepected behavior from multiple bitwise shifts on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25393058/995714), [Why does combining two shifts of a uint8_t produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22702091/995714)

Comment: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Comment: So why not just `x & 0x0FFF`?

Answer (score 9):

Happens due to integer promotion.  On systems where `int` is larger than 16 bits, your expression is converted to

```
uint16_t a = (int)((int)x << 4) >> 4;
```

and the upper bits are not stripped therefore.

Comment: "and the upper bits are not stripped " --> when the `int/unsigned` bit width >= 20 (But do not know of any system with 17-20 bit `int` width.)

Comment: uint16_t a = 0xabcd, b = a << 4;   printf("%x\n", b >> 4);

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print out "bcd", maybe you can do like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint16_t x = 0xabcd; // I want to print out "bcd"        // step 1
    uint16_t c = x << 4 ;                                    // step 2
    uint16_t a = c >> 4;                                     // step 3

    printf("After clearing first four bits: %x\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

above output is :

```
After clearing first four bits: bcd
```

## explanation:

when run step 1:

```
x is 1010101111001101 (binary)          // 1010(a) 1011(b) 1100(c) 1101(d)
```

go to step 2:

```
c is 1011110011010000 (binary)          // 1011(b) 1100(c) 1101(d) 0000(0)
```

finally go to step 3:

```
a is 101111001101 (binary)              // 1011(b) 1100(c) 1101(d)
```

Comment: `x` will be promoted to a (signed) `int`, not to an "unsigned 32-bits" value

Comment: @ensc,sorry.I changed.