# Do compilers optimize out net zero bit shifts?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-optimization, clang++

I have some code like the following code block (I am not allowed to post the original code) inside a `.cpp` file that I think is being compiled by `clang++` (`Ubuntu clang version 3.5.2-3ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_352/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.2)`).
It looks like `C` code, because we are using `GoogleTest` for testing our `C` code. Anyways:

```
size_t const SHIFT = 4;
uint8_t var, var2;
/* Omitted: Code that sets var to, say 00011000 (base 2) */
var2 = var;
var = var << SHIFT >> SHIFT; // [1] result is 00011000 (base 2) (tested with printf)
var2 = var2 << SHIFT;
var2 = var2 >> SHIFT; // [2] result is 00001000 (base 2) (tested with printf)
```

Now, why does comment `[1]` hold true? I was assuming that the corresponding line would result in the top 4 bits being zeroed out. But I found out that this isn't true; the program simply restores the original value.

> Is this some language defined behavior, or is `clang` compiling out a supposedly useless bit shift?

(I checked associativity (using [this table on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), assuming that associativity/precedence of basic operators won't differ between versions of `C++` and probably not between `C++` and `C` either, at least not in 'current versions') and it seems like the RHS expression at `[1]` should really yield the same result as the two following statements)

Comment: Integer promotion.

Comment: Ah lol. Thanks @Mysticial ! Do you care to answer? Otherwise I'll just answer it myself quickly. I guess the takeaway for me is to rather use `&` instead of left and right shifting...

Comment: Also, generally shift left followed by shift right by the same amount of bits, is not the identity operation as you seem to expect. It performs a mask operation.

Comment: If var isn't initialised then the result is undefined behaviour, which means (among other things) that it is legal if var2 == var, with no shifts produced.

Comment: I wouldn't say a coïncidence. If the values are "within range" (I mean: no 1 bits are shifted off left), then the values are identical.

Comment: fyi: as @Mysticial says plus with: g++ 5.1.0: warning: conversion to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]

Comment: @RichardCritten is there a `clang` flag to enable such warnings? I didn't get any...

Comment: @polynomial_donut same flag: clang 5.0.0 ( tested on https://godbolt.org/g/kXVkQz ) <source>:6:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'int' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wconversion]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are seeing is a result of **integer promotions**.  Any value with a type of lower rank than `int`, when used in an expression, is promoted to `int`.

This is detail in section  6.3.1.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> *2* The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may
>   be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`)
>     whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and
>     `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
>   bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.  All other types are unchanged by the
>   integer promotions.

In this case:

```
var = var << SHIFT >> SHIFT;
```

`var` is first promoted to `int`.  This type is at least 16 bits wide, and most likely 32 bits wide.  So the value being operated on is `0x00000018`.  A left shift of 4 results in `0x00000180`, and subsequently right shifting results in `0x00000018`.

The result is then stored in a `uint_8`.  Since the value fits in a variable of this type, no conversion is required and `0x18` is stored.

Comment: Am I wrong by saying `var` is promoted to `size_t` aka `unsigned int` (not `int`)?

Comment: But there can be cases [due to promotions that could have unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22702091/1708801)

Comment: @polynomial_donut That is *not* correct because 1) `size_t` may be larger than `unsigned int`, and 2) the standard specifically states that the type of a promoted value is `int`.

Comment: The rule of thumb if you're not interested in language lawyer level of detail is that integer promotion sucks in C and C++. And if you think that's bad, wait till you get to function overloading ambiguities with integer types (numeric types in general).

Comment: @Mysticial Luckily, we are working with `C`, so no `C++` voodoo :) (*except for basic unit testing code -_-)

Comment: @Mysticial btw.: Funny coincidence, we almost have the same names :) cheers

Comment: @dbush The fact that integral promotion only results in `int` or `unsigned int`, and the process is instead called "integral conversion" when larger types are involved, always throws me off…

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
var = var << SHIFT >> SHIFT;
```

is not semantically equivelent to

```
var = var << SHIFT ;
var = var >> SHIFT ;
```

That would require:

```
var = (uint8_t)(var << SHIFT) >> SHIFT ;
```

which illustrates the effective difference between the two - the observed behaviour does not require optimisation, rather it is *required* by language definition with respect to type promotion rules in expressions.

That said, it is also entirely possible that a compiler could optimise out the shifts.  Optimisation may not change the result where the behaviour is *defined* as it is in this case.